# URL-encode в cp-1251

Tags: c#, кодировка

Есть текст

%E4%E8%EC%EA%E0%E0%E0%E01998

Артемий декодер говорит что это 
**URL-encoded → CP1251** и что текст **димкаааа1998**

Пробую сделать в шарпе, но почему то результат не тот который должен получиться. На выходе получается какая-то котовасия

```
var str = Uri.UnescapeDataString("%FB%E2%F4%FB%E2%F4%FB%E2%F4");
            Encoding srcEncodingFormat = Encoding.UTF8;
            Encoding dstEncodingFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
            byte[] originalByteString = srcEncodingFormat.GetBytes(str);
            byte[] convertedByteString = Encoding.Convert(srcEncodingFormat,
            dstEncodingFormat, originalByteString);
            string finalString = dstEncodingFormat.GetString(convertedByteString);
```

Comment: Странно, мне декодер Лебедева вернул текст `ьарьарьар` и кодировку `URL-encoded → KOI8-R + CP1251 → KOI8-R `

Comment: http://www.codenet.ru/services/urlencode-urldecode/ - тут достовернее выглядит, вставьте в поле для `windows-1251`

Comment: пардон, строку не ту дал. вот строка %E4%E8%EC%EA%E0%E0%E0%E01998

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо вот так наверное:

```
var strEnc = "%E4%E8%EC%EA%E0%E0%E0%E01998";
var win1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
var strDec = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(strEnc, win1251);
```

Comment: А как вы догадались что там надо декодировать)?

Comment: @Radzhab из описания вопроса. Исходная строка это url-encoded байты cp1251, логично чтобы получить юникод надо этой кодировкой и декодировать. Или вопрос не про это?